# In Ruby, what is the correct way to inherit from parent class and parent's parent module?

Tags: ruby, oop

#### Code

```rb
require "fluent/plugin/input"

module Fluent::Plugin

  class ParentInput < Fluent::Plugin::Input

    Fluent::Plugin.register_input("parent", self)
    # Imagine parent_param as an instance variable that ia accessed as @parent_param, which is "Hello"
    config_param :parent_param, :string, :default => "Hello"

    # 1. Flunetd runs this first
    def initialize()
      super
      log.info "Inside Parent initialize()"
    end

    # 2. Flunetd runs this after initialize
    def configure(conf)
      log.info "Inside Parent configure()"
      log.info "@parent_param=", @parent_param
      Child.new().main()
    end

    # 3. Flunetd runs this after configure
    def start()
      super
      log.info "Inside Parent start"
      hello_world = hello_world()
      log.info "hello_world", hello_world # Hello World
    end
    
    def hello_world()
      log.info "Inside Parent hello_world()"
      return @parent_var + " World"
    end

  end # Parent class

  class Child < ParentInput
    def initialize()
      super
      log.info "Inside Child initialize()"
      @hello_world = hello_world()
    end
    def main()
      log.info "Inside Child main()"
      log.info @hello_world
    end
  end # Child class

end # Fluent::Plugin module
```

#### Code Explanation

- The goal of the code is to set things up in `configure()` before moving on to `start()`.
- Throughout the code `hello_world()` is accessed by the `Parent` and once by `Child` at `configure()`
- `Parent` class runs the main logic. The way it is defined is as per the docs. - The `Child` class is something I've added in addition to seperate the functionality. In reality it does more things. I've simplified it for the sake of demonstration.
- `initialize()` – `super` is used here because `log` will not work without it. Without it it will be `nil`.
- When flunetd is run below output can be seen, it highlights the order of execution:

```
Inside Parent initialize()
Inside Parent configure()
@parent_param=Hello
Inside Child initialize()
Inside Parent hello_world()
`hello_world': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
...
```

- As you can see from above `@parent_var` is not available in child class, however `log` seems to be available as it was able to print `"Inside Child initialize()"`.

#### Problem

- What is correct way to inherit from:

  - parent's variables/parameters (Ex: `parent_param`)?
  - parent's methods (Ex: `hello_world()`)?
  - Parent's parent or module (Ex: `log` from `Fluentd`)?

Comment: In Ruby you cannot inherit from a module, so there is no such thing as "parent's parent module". Also, your assumption about "`@parent_var` is not available" is incorrect - instance variables are always available, but can be not defined yet. Referring to an undefined instance variable returns `nil` (that in your case doesn't respond to `+` method).

Comment: Also, it's not clear why would one expect `@parent_var` to be defined - it is not set anywhere in the code snippet that you posted.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov It is set in the line `config_param :parent_param, :string, :default => "Hello"`. The value `"Hello"` can be accessed inside the `Parent` class in the line `log.info "@parent_param=", @parent_param` but it cannot be accessed inside the `Child` class.

Answer (score 0):

you should be good by replacing `parent_var` with `parent_params`

`parent_var` isn't set/defined anywhere